# Reading Files from Directory one by one

Tags: c, file

I have files in a directory named as 1.txt ,2.txt and so on. I am reading these files by:

```
int counter=0;

unsigned char buffer[212]={0};

while(1)

{

sprintf(buffer,"path/%d.txt",++counter);

FILE *fp = fopen(buffer,"rb");

// some operations..

fclose(fp); 

}
```

I have more than 800 txt files in the folder(1.txt - 800.txt). But when around 500 files are read
i.e from 1.txt to 500.txt it exits and doesnot read the next files.

Can anyone rectify this problem? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, to insert your code parts please use `{}` tool box button.

Comment: Is it always on the same file that it exits?  Is there anything special about the next file it was supposed to process?

Comment: @Dason I tried reading other directories as well but this problem persists. I also tried long/unsigned int etc in place of "int" counter. But it could read only 7 extra files.

Comment: Do you get `fp` as `NULL`? If that is the case try to print the error message using `perror` & see what the error is.

Comment: Please show  some operations.. code, may be your program run out of memory.

Comment: Is that your actual call to `fopen`?

Comment: Its showing some error Stream!=NULL

Comment: @Aizen: What are "some operations.."?

Comment: @AusCBloke: Adding a string to the end of each file.

Comment: @Aizen: Are you sure each file actually exists? Try checking the return value of `fopen`, and tell us what happens when the program exis. Does it give a seg fault or what? Can you run the program in a debugger to find the line causing the problem? Also you've got an infinite loop in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are running uout of file descriptors (max is for example 500 per process). Try to use the readdir function.

Comment: He is closing each file before opening the next one, so as far as I know this should not be the case.